# Override keyword in Google Assistant for custom action?

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-home, google-assistant-sdk

so I've been looking into making custom action with API.ai / Dialogflow and I've even tried some things out. One thing I'm a little confused about though is if it's possible to just have an "intent" that just sends whatever you say to a server (one that I would be hosting maybe on a rasp pi) AND can be triggered without having to "run" an app. Most examples have the user say something like "OK google, run mySuperCoolApp" and THEN they can say whatever custom stuff they have set up. I would like to be able to designate some keyword, (maybe "now"?) so that my intent will run, and then send whatever I said to some server I have set up with a webhook.

Example: "OK google, now do task 1"
Then webhook gets triggered (because now is the first word) and sends that string to my server which then does something...

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but only locally. ie You could override only on the assistant running locally.
This is done by intercepting the assistant to get the user's query and process it to do local fulfilment.

You could do something like

```
def process_event(self, event):
    if event.type = EventType.ON_RECOGNIZING_SPEECH_FINISHED and event.args:
        query = event.args['text']
        if query == 'now do task':  # check if it matches your command
            self.assistant.stop_conversation() # Stop the usual reply from the Assistant 
            call_a_function() # This will call a function locally to perform a task
```

Comment: Ah ok. So in other words, this is only possible on your own custom device? Like I probably couldn't get a google home to do this, as I would need to change the internal code to catch my custom keyword?

Comment: Yeah. But there is also a workaround using IFTTT. https://ifttt.com/google_assistant for simple actions. 
IFTTT doesn't have any app invocations, and you can directly call a command. 
AFAIK, to invoke an app, there has to be an app invocation.